# Dynamically change the width of a button in Android

Tags: android, dynamic, button

My question is very simple, I'm trying to dynamically change the width of this button :

```
<Button> 
    android:layout_height="35dip" 
    android:background="@drawable/buttonlesson" 
    android:text="Level 3 [TAP HERE]" 
    android:onClick="MenuLI1L3" 
    android:layout_width="300dp" 
    android:id="@+id/II3"
</Button>
```

Here is the code I use :

```
 Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.II3);
 myButton.setWidth(10);
 myButton.setText("kl");
```

Text indeed change but not the width. Sound like there is a bug.
There is another button on its right which suppose to fill the gap when this button is reduced to 10 pixel, so I can't change the LinearLayout above too.

Any explanation & solution ? It should work no? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a suggestion try calling invalidate() on the parent view (which will cause drawing invocations to all the children - including your button).  This might not work because what you also need is for the button to re-run its onMeasure() logic (which runs prior to drawing).

Play with either invalidating or any other method which will cause the parent to invoke the onMeasure of the children.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! invalidate() on the layer or on the button havn't done anything though.... but myButton.bringToFront(); somehow worked out.

Comment: I haven't played with bringToFront() but I can't help but wonder if it causes the button to run its onMeasure()?  Well, at least you're up and working.  Nicely done.

Answer (score 2):

I assume wrap_content doesn't work for your in your specific case, right?
If you need absolute width, then you need to assign that via new LayoutParameters, i.e.

```
myButton.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    30 * someDensityFactor, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
))
```

where the someDensityFactor is your screen density (float). You also might need to invalidate your layout then as well in order to get the button repainted.